# VariantClear exception when passing COM object to VB 6 with opened watch window

Tags: c++, com, vb6, atl

Why this error is occurred? References count is increased, threading models is single appartment. Coll-object and EmptyColl-function both located inside one dll. Default calling conversion of ATL project is __stdcall. Same error occured with other objects inside this dll.

> VariantClear throws exception when clearing VARIANT with NULL-object:
>   Exception thrown at 0x75C14974 (oleaut32.dll) in VB6.EXE: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000008.

frmMain.frm (error, see below why):

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim c As Coll
  Set c = EmptyColl
  'error when ends here with variable "c" in the watch window.
End Sub
```

frmMain.frm (no error):

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim c2 As Coll 'instead of Coll can be any object of same library
  Set c2 = New Coll 'creation
  Set c2 = Nothing 'destroying (optionaly)
  Dim c As Coll
  Set c = EmptyColl
  'no error
End Sub
```

filyus.idl:

```
[
  object,
  uuid(6FA7FAEB-5CE3-4A80-9288-2667EE5E7596),
  dual,
  nonextensible,
  pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IColl : IDispatch{
  //some methods
};

[
  uuid(157F3D2F-A427-4D5A-B908-87868297EA43),
  version(1.0),
]
library Filyus
{
  importlib("stdole2.tlb");
  [
    dllname("Filyus")
  ]
  module Filyus{
    [entry("EmptyColl")]
    HRESULT EmptyColl([out, retval] IColl** Coll);
  }
};
```

filyus.def:

```
LIBRARY

EXPORTS
  DllCanUnloadNow       PRIVATE
  DllGetClassObject PRIVATE
  DllRegisterServer PRIVATE
  DllUnregisterServer   PRIVATE
  DllInstall        PRIVATE
  EmptyColl
```

ole.h:

```cpp
extern HRESULT EmptyColl(IColl** Coll);
```

ole.cpp:

```cpp
HRESULT EmptyColl(IColl** Coll) {
  HRESULT hr; CComObject<CColl>* Object;
  if (Coll != nullptr) {
    hr = CComObject<CColl>::CreateInstance(&Object);
    if (hr == S_OK) {
      Object->AddRef();
      *Coll = Object; //same error with using QueryInterface
    }
  }
  else hr = E_POINTER;
  return hr;
}
```

Comment: "*Same error occured with other objects inside this dll*" - then clearly you are doing something fundamentally wrong inside your DLL.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing more of your DLL's code. In particular, how it is declaring and setting up the `CColl` class, and other classes you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

`EmptyColl()` needs to use the `__stdcall` calling convention:

```
extern HRESULT __stdcall EmptyColl(IColl** Coll);

HRESULT __stdcall EmptyColl(IColl** Coll) {
    //...
}
```

Alternatively, use the `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` macro, which resolves to `__stdcall`:

```
extern HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmptyColl(IColl** Coll);

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE EmptyColl(IColl** Coll) {
    //...
}
```

Without a calling convention declared, by default a C/C++ compiler will use `__cdecl` instead unless configured differently.  `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` manage the call stack differently. You will corrupt the call stack if you don't use the correct calling convention.  COM standards require `__stdcall`, and that is what VB expects.

Comment: Default calling conversion of my project is  __stdcall.

Comment: Still better to be explicit about the calling convention in code instead of relying on project settings.

Comment: Offset 8 from the beginning of a COM interface is the vtable entry for the COM object's `Release()` method. An AV at address `00000008` means `Release()` is being called on a null interface pointer. `VariantClear()` does call `Release()` if the `VARIANT`'s type is `VT_UNKNOWN` or `VT_DISPATCH`, but if the `VARIANT` is being managed correctly then it should never have a null interface pointer in it. An empty VARIANT should have a `vt` value of `VT_EMPTY` instead. That said, I do see that `EmptyColl()` is not initializing the `Coll` pointer to null if `CreateInstance()` fails.

Comment: else *Coll = nullptr; not fixed the problem. Look at the frmMain.frm (no error) code above please.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurred because of wrong access to the object.
CComPtr is for client side, CComObject is for server side (direct access, obtain it only when you already created any object of this library).

Correct ole.cpp:

```
HRESULT EmptyColl(IColl** Coll) {
  HRESULT hr; CComPtr<IColl> Object;
  if (Coll != nullptr) {
    hr = Object.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Coll);
    if (hr == S_OK) {
      Object.CopyTo(Coll);
    }
  }
  else hr = E_POINTER;
  return hr;
}
```

Comment: The `EmptyColl()` implementation is server-side code, not client-side code. `EmptyColl()` is not creating an instance of a COM object from another library, it is creating a new instance of the `CColl` class that resides in the same DLL as `EmptyColl()`.  The OP's use of `CComObject` is correct in this situation (provided `CColl` derives from  `CComObjectRoot` or `CComObjectRootEx`, that is). Using `CComPtr` like you suggest, while correct for client-side code, is incorrect for `EmptyColl()`'s server-side code.

Comment: @remy-lebeau Look at the code marked "frmMain.frm (no error)" above, after any object of this library is created (and optionaly destroyed) no error is occurred. Therefore to use CComObject you need some already created from client-side object, possible application - creation of child and related objects.

Comment: No, you don't need an active object to already exist in order to use `CComObject` for creating new objects. I have written plenty of COM servers that return new objects when called, and `CComObject` works just fine for that when used properly. The problem is not in the code showed, as evident by the "*Same error occured with other objects inside this dll*" comment. The DLL has to be doing something else wrong, but those details have not been made available yet.

Comment: No more code needed to reproduce problem. Tested in the new project.